# Get nested data c.<type>.<type> in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, json

I've been searching everywhere for this seemingly simple action: I'd like to select only a certain few data type from a nested source.

The closest that I can get to the solution is this:

```sql
SELECT c.receipt_number, c.millitime, c.email, c.phone, c.shipping, c.shipping_note, c.amount_paid, i.description, i.quantity
FROM c
JOIN i IN c.line_items
WHERE c.millitime > 1627813253000
```

But this will create lots of duplicated data, like the `receipt_number`, `email`, etc in the example:

```json
[
    {
        "receipt_number": null,
        "millitime": 1627813377000,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "phone": "000000000",
        "shipping": {
            "address": {
                "city": "Sydney",
                "country": "AU",
                "line1": "Test Street",
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "3000",
                "state": "VIC"
            },
            "name": "New Cust"
        },
        "shipping_note": "Please knock on door.",
        "amount_paid": 104,
        "description": "Curry Chicken",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "receipt_number": null,
        "millitime": 1627813377000,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "phone": "000000000",
        "shipping": {
            "address": {
                "city": "Sydney",
                "country": "AU",
                "line1": "Test Street",
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "3000",
                "state": "VIC"
            },
            "name": "New Cust"
        },
        "shipping_note": "Please knock on door.",
        "amount_paid": 104,
        "description": "Chicken Noodle",
        "quantity": 8
    }
]
```

Is there a way to create a nested result of `c.line_items` with just the desired data `description` and `quantity`? The final result should be similar to:

```json
[
    {
        "receipt_number": null,
        "millitime": 1627813377000,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "phone": "000000000",
        "shipping": {
            "address": {
                "city": "Sydney",
                "country": "AU",
                "line1": "Test Street",
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "3000",
                "state": "VIC"
            },
            "name": "New Cust"
        },
        "shipping_note": "Please knock on door.",
        "amount_paid": 104,
        "line_items": [
        {
            "description": "Chicken Noodle",
            "quantity": 8
        },
        {
            "description": "Curry Chicken",
            "quantity": 1
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Mysql and azure cosmos db are two different database products. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same in

1. You can use **distinct** keyword to remove duplicates from the results.
2. Add c.line_items to your select list and change i.description, i.quantity to c.description, c.quantity to add view under line_items.

**Query**:

```
SELECT distinct c.receipt_number, c.millitime, c.email, c.phone, c.shipping, c.shipping_note, c.amount_paid, c.line_items     
FROM c     
JOIN i IN c.line_items     
WHERE c.millitime > 1627813253000
```

**Result**:

[image]

Reference: [Azure Cosmos DB SQL query - JSON items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-getting-started#query-the-json-items)